# Integrals involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration

Can anyone please help me in finding the integral
$\int\limits_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\left|t-\frac{1}{6}\right|}{((1-t)a+tb)^{2}}t^{s}\mathrm{d}t$ where $0<a<b$ and $0<s\leq1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you explain the context in which you found the problem, include any work you have done, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x= (1-t)a+bt  \Rightarrow t=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$. Also, when $t=0$ we have $x=a$ and when $t=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Now, 
\begin{align}
\left| {t - \frac{1}{6}} \right| = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 t - \frac{1}{6},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{1}{6} \le t \le \frac{1}{2} \\ 
  \\ 
 \frac{1}{6} - t,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,0 \le t \le \frac{1}{6} \\ 
 \end{array} \right. &= \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}} - \frac{1}{6},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{1}{6} \le \frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}} \le \frac{1}{2} \\ 
  \\ 
 \frac{1}{6} - \frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,0 \le \frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}} \le \frac{1}{6} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\\
 &= \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}} - \frac{1}{6},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{{b + 5a}}{6} \le x \le \frac{{a + b}}{2} \\ 
  \\ 
 \frac{1}{6} - \frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a \le x \le \frac{{b + 5a}}{6} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\end{align} 
Now,
[
\begin{align}
 I &= \int_0^{1/2} {\frac{{\left| {t - {\textstyle{1 \over 6}}} \right|}}{{\left( {\left( {1 - t} \right)a + tb} \right)^2 }} \cdot t^s dt}  \\ 
  &= \int_a^{{\textstyle{{a + b} \over 2}}} {\frac{{\left| {{\textstyle{{x - a} \over {b - a}}} - {\textstyle{1 \over 6}}} \right|}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left( {\frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}}} \right)^s \frac{{dx}}{{b - a}}}  \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{{b - a}}\int_a^{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}} {\frac{{\left( {{\textstyle{1 \over 6}} - {\textstyle{{x - a} \over {b - a}}}} \right)}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left( {\frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}}} \right)^s dx}  + \frac{1}{{b - a}}\int_{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}}^{{\textstyle{{a + b} \over 2}}} {\frac{{\left( {{\textstyle{{x - a} \over {b - a}}} - {\textstyle{1 \over 6}}} \right)}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left( {\frac{{x - a}}{{b - a}}} \right)^s dx}  \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{{\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 1} }}\int_a^{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}} {\frac{{\left( {b - 6x + 5a} \right)}}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)x^2 }} \cdot \left( {x - a} \right)^s dx}  
\\
&\qquad+ \frac{1}{{\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 1} }}\int_{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}}^{{\textstyle{{a + b} \over 2}}} {\frac{{\left( {6x - 5a - b} \right)}}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)x^2 }} \cdot \left( {x - a} \right)^s dx}  \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\int_a^{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}} {\frac{{\left( {b - 6x + 5a} \right)}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left( {x - a} \right)^s dx}  
\\
&\qquad+ \frac{1}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\int_{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}}^{{\textstyle{{a + b} \over 2}}} {\frac{{\left( {6x - 5a - b} \right)}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left( {x - a} \right)^s dx}  
 \end{align}
Using the expansion 
\begin{align}
\left( {x - a} \right)^s  = a^s \left( {\frac{x}{a} - 1} \right)^s  = a^s \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {\frac{x}{a}} \right)^k } 
\end{align}
we may write
[
\begin{align}
 I &= \frac{1}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\int_a^{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}} {\frac{{\left( {b - 6x + 5a} \right)}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left\{ {a^s \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {\frac{x}{a}} \right)^k } } \right\}dx}  \\ 
  &\qquad+ \frac{1}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\int_{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}}^{{\textstyle{{a + b} \over 2}}} {\frac{{\left( {6x - 5a - b} \right)}}{{x^2 }} \cdot \left\{ {a^s \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {\frac{x}{a}} \right)^k } } \right\}dx}  \\ 
  &= \frac{{a^s }}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^k }}\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\int_a^{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}} {\left( {b - 6x + 5a} \right)x^{k - 2} dx} }  \\ 
  &\qquad+ \frac{{a^s }}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^k }}\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\int_{{\textstyle{{b + 5a} \over 2}}}^{\frac{{a + b}}{2}} {\left( {6x - 5a - b} \right)x^{k - 2} dx} }  \\ 
  &= \frac{{a^s }}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^k }}\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left. {\left( {b\frac{{x^{k - 1} }}{{k - 1}} - 6\frac{{x^k }}{k} + 5a\frac{{x^{k - 1} }}{{k - 1}}} \right)} \right|_a^{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}} }  \\ 
  &\qquad+ \frac{{a^s }}{{6\left( {b - a} \right)^{s + 2} }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^k }}\left( \begin{array}{l}
 s \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left. {\left( {6\frac{{x^k }}{k} - 5a\frac{{x^{k - 1} }}{{k - 1}} - b\frac{{x^{k - 1} }}{{k - 1}}} \right)} \right|_{\frac{{b + 5a}}{6}}^{\frac{{a + b}}{2}} }  
 \end{align}